# Highlight Circumference of a circle using D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tooltip

How to highlight the circumference of a circle in d3.js when the user hovers overs it? I wish to bolden the width of the circumference of a circle when the user hovers over the same

[image: As shown in the example here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500);
        
      var circle = svg.append('circle')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(250,250)')
        .attr('r', 200)
        .style('fill', 'steelblue')
        .style('stroke-width', '15px')
        .style('stroke', 'none')
        .on('mouseover', function(){
          d3.select(this)
            .style('stroke', 'orange');
        })
        .on('mouseover', function(){
          circle
            .style('stroke', 'orange');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(){
          circle
            .style('stroke', 'none');
        })
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You Mark. This was of tremendous help. I was able to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with plain CSS, no need to use D3.js. Example:

```css
circle {
  fill: lightblue;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

circle:hover {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Oscar!